# Flutter scroll List view if Keyboard is covering Textfield

Tags: flutter, listview, dart, keyboard

This is how my page looks like at the moment:

[image]
[image]

The problem is that if I click one of the lower `TextFields` I get an error because the `Keyboard` is covering it...

My goal is that the `headerLabel` ("Neuer Kontakt") and the `bottomButton` ("Speichern") should be fixed. The `TextFields` in the middle should be in a scrollable list. If the user taps on a `textField`, the list scrolls so the `textField` is right above  the `keyboard` (only for the ones where the keyboard would cover the textField).  How can I achieve that? Or what is a Flutter way to handle this kind of design? I couldn't find anything on this.

This is what I tried but it does nothing when the keyboard appears:

```
return Scaffold(
  body: GestureDetector(
    onTap: () {
      FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
    },
    child: SafeArea(
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          horizontal: scaleWidth(17),
        ),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: scaleWidth(15),
            ),
            PageHeaderBackButton(
              context: context,
            ),
            Text(
              locales.translate('createEmergencyContactHeadline'),
              style: AppTextStyles.h1,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: scaleWidth(30),
            ),
            SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  TextFieldWithHeader(
                      headerLabel: 'Name des Kontakts',
                      placeHolderText: 'z.B. Elfriede, Ehefrau'),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: scaleWidth(30),
                  ),
                  TextFieldWithHeader(
                      headerLabel: 'Telefonnummer',
                      placeHolderText: 'Telefonnummer hinzufügen'),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: scaleWidth(30),
                  ),
                  TextFieldWithHeader(
                      headerLabel: 'Telefonnummer1',
                      placeHolderText: 'Telefonnummer hinzufügen'),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: scaleWidth(30),
                  ),
                  TextFieldWithHeader(
                      headerLabel: 'Telefonnummer2',
                      placeHolderText: 'Telefonnummer hinzufügen'),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Spacer(),
            BottomActionButton(
              nextButtonTappedCallback: () => {
                Navigator.pop(context),
              },
              title: 'Speichern',
              shouldShowArrowIcon: false,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: scaleWidth(17),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: you can more code add here

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the `SingleChildScrollView` inside an `Expanded` widget? Also, remove the spacer.

Comment: @MdOmorFaruqe what exactly do you need?

Comment: @rickimaru the `spacer` is just there so the `BottomActionButton` is at the bottom, I test it with expanded

Comment: function code details

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code

```
return Scaffold(
  body:SingleChildScrollView(
    child: GestureDetector(
    onTap: () {
      FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
    },
    child: SafeArea(
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          horizontal: scaleWidth(17),
        ),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: scaleWidth(15),
            ),
            PageHeaderBackButton(
              context: context,
            ),
            Text(
              locales.translate('createEmergencyContactHeadline'),
              style: AppTextStyles.h1,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: scaleWidth(30),
            ),
            SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  TextFieldWithHeader(
                      headerLabel: 'Name des Kontakts',
                      placeHolderText: 'z.B. Elfriede, Ehefrau'),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: scaleWidth(30),
                  ),
                  TextFieldWithHeader(
                      headerLabel: 'Telefonnummer',
                      placeHolderText: 'Telefonnummer hinzufügen'),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: scaleWidth(30),
                  ),
                  TextFieldWithHeader(
                      headerLabel: 'Telefonnummer1',
                      placeHolderText: 'Telefonnummer hinzufügen'),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: scaleWidth(30),
                  ),
                  TextFieldWithHeader(
                      headerLabel: 'Telefonnummer2',
                      placeHolderText: 'Telefonnummer hinzufügen'),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Spacer(),
            BottomActionButton(
              nextButtonTappedCallback: () => {
                Navigator.pop(context),
              },
              title: 'Speichern',
              shouldShowArrowIcon: false,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: scaleWidth(17),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),)
);
```